# How to get multiple words from csv

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I want to get multiple words from CSV file and combine forward sentence.
Awk command is very useful. But this is not expectation.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
command:
awk -F , '{                 #process to csv file
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)          #process to every row
{if($i~/bbb|ccc/)           #if find bbb or ccc
{print $1","$2","$i}}       #print column1 and column2 and bbb and ccc
}'

CSV file content:
r1c1,r1c2,bbb,
r2c1,r2c2,bbb,ccc
r3c1,r3c2,xxx,yyy

↓

output:
r1c1,r1c2,bbb,
r2c1,r2c2,bbb
r2c1,r2c2,ccc

expectation:
r1c1,r1c2,bbb,
r2c1,r2c2,bbb,ccc
```

r1c1 is row1 and col1, r1c2 is row1 and col2.
xxx,yyy is not contained bbb or ccc, so this is not displayed.

Comment: Please do explain on what is the Logic of getting expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: I wrote an explanation.

Comment: With the example given, there is no need to change anything, so you can use `cat inputfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F, '{
   s = $1 FS $2
   for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^(bbb|ccc)$/) {
         s = s FS $i
         ok = 1
      }
   if (ok) print s
   ok = 0
}' file

r1c1,r1c2,bbb
r2c1,r2c2,bbb,ccc
```